# Jackson ObjectMapper does not deserialize lowercase string

Tags: java, jackson

I have a json as a string:

```json
{
    "passnummer": "passnummer",
    "nummerDesAufenthaltstitels": "nummerDesAufenthaltstitels",
    "ppkNummer": "ppkNummer",
    "fingerabdruckreferenznummer": "fingerabdruckreferenznummer"
}
```

there is no consistency for the seperation of the words meaning that some
keys are camel case and some are not. I have no influence on that.
And I cannot change the model.

I have to read this string into a Java Object. I also have no
influennce on the Java Model so I cannot add @JsonProperty or @JsonAlias
annotations or anything else to the fields of the model.

So the java model looks like this:

```java
  public static class Request {
    protected String passnummer;
    protected String nummerDesAufenthaltstitels;
    protected String ppkNummer;
    protected String fingerabdruckreferenznummer;

    public String getPassnummer() {
      return this.passnummer;
    }

    public void setPassnummer(String value) {
      this.passnummer = value;
    }

    public String getNummerDesAufenthaltstitels() {
      return this.nummerDesAufenthaltstitels;
    }

    public void setNummerDesAufenthaltstitels(String value) {
      this.nummerDesAufenthaltstitels = value;
    }

    public String getPpkNummer() {
      return this.ppkNummer;
    }

    public void setPpkNummer(String value) {
      this.ppkNummer = value;
    }

    public String getFingerabdruckreferenznummer() {
      return this.fingerabdruckreferenznummer;
    }

    public void setFingerabdruckreferenznummer(String value) {
      this.fingerabdruckreferenznummer = value;
    }
}
```

When I deserialize the json into the java object and print the values:

```java
Request request = objectmapper.readValue(jsonPayload, Request.class);

System.out.println("passnummer: " + request.getPassnummer());
System.out.println("nummerDesAufenthaltstitels: " + request.getNummerDesAufenthaltstitels());
System.out.println("ppkNummer: " + request.getPpkNummer());
System.out.println("fingerabdruckreferenznummer: " + request.getFingerabdruckreferenznummer());
```

I get the following result:

```
passnummer: passnummer
nummerDesAufenthaltstitels: nummerDesAufenthaltstitels
ppkNummer: ppkNummer
fingerabdruckreferenznummer: null
```

So my question is: Why cant objectMapper desieralize `fingerabdruckreferenznummer`?

**EDIT**

ObjectMapper config:

```java
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

    module.addSerializer(TeilbekanntesDatumMitUnbekannt.class, new DateSerializer());

    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    objectMapper.configure(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    objectMapper.configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.setVisibility(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

    return objectMapper;
  }
```

**EDIT 2**

If I use a play `new ObjectMapper()` instead I get:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "fingerabdruckreferenznummer"
```

Comment: It works here as exptected with a 'vanilla' objectmapper. `new ObjectMapper()`. So, question is, what is your `ObjectMapper` like? Or you pass the wrong json-payload.

Comment: *I have a json as a string:* but that's not your json is it?

Comment: I assume: typo in `payload` ;)

Comment: im sorry I forgot to add the objectmapper config

Comment: you really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
(which *includes* the json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `ObjectMapper` (except the parts that you didn't post) and this code, the result is as expected:

### Code

```
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    //        module.addSerializer(TeilbekanntesDatumMitUnbekannt.class, new DateSerializer());
    //            objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());

    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.configure(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    objectMapper.configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.setVisibility(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));


    final String jsonPayload = """
             {
                 "passnummer": "1passnummer",
                 "nummerDesAufenthaltstitels": "2nummerDesAufenthaltstitels",
                 "ppkNummer": "3ppkNummer",
                 "fingerabdruckreferenznummer": "4fingerabdruckreferenznummer"
             }               
            """;
    final Request request = objectMapper.readValue(jsonPayload, Request.class);

    System.out.println("passnummer: " + request.getPassnummer());
    System.out.println("nummerDesAufenthaltstitels: " + request.getNummerDesAufenthaltstitels());
    System.out.println("ppkNummer: " + request.getPpkNummer());
    System.out.println("fingerabdruckreferenznummer: " + request.getFingerabdruckreferenznummer());
```

### Result

```
passnummer: 1passnummer
nummerDesAufenthaltstitels: 2nummerDesAufenthaltstitels
ppkNummer: 3ppkNummer
fingerabdruckreferenznummer: 4fingerabdruckreferenznummer
```

So either your json-payload is different, or your `objectmapper` has some additional config.

Comment: Are you sure the Request class is exactly like you posted? There is probably a typo somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectMapper` could be configured to filter out certain fields. Create you own ObjectMapper or make sure you know what is configured.
This could be done with a Mixin.

```
this.objectMapper = objectMapper.addMixIn(Request.class, MyMixin.class);

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"fingerabdruckreferenznummer", "field2"})
private interface MyMixin {}
```